# When to use setter attribute 'copy' in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, setter

I understand that normally you use **copy** for NSStrings, so that your property stays as the same value as when you assigned it, even when there's an attempt to re-set it somewhere else.

But I am having hard time completely understanding this concept. Doesn't this apply to basically any kind of object (not just NSStrings)?

So my question is, **"What kind of properties should I set as 'copy', and why?"**

Comment: blocks also, because there are current scope variables have to passed in block

Comment: all classes that support <NSCopying> protocol. Copied object have same data but refer to another address in memory

Comment: @NeverBe That's misleading. While you *can* use this with any class that implements `NSCopying`, the question is when you *should*. Blocks are a special case because they become legitimately useless once their stack frame goes away without a copy. Otherwise, the only general rule I can think of is "mutable data you *want* to have a copy of to avoid other owners of the data clobbering it, instead of sharing ownership between objects"

Comment: @NeverBe Also, you won't always get a different memory address, so stating that it does this can be misleading. Some objects return their own memory address as an optimization even after being copied if they know they are immutable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Objects that are simple bits of data, like strings, that won't have references to a ton of other objects in your application are great for copying.

Now you can, of course, retain things like strings instead. This will work fine. But what if you had a mutable string instead, and you modified it. Now every other object that had a reference to that string will see that modification. This may not be what you want. This is one reason copying is "simpler", because any changes to that data is localized to just that bit of code.

On the other hand, lets say you have a instance of a class you wrote for your app. It has references to other objects in your app, it has a ton of it's own strings or other values in it, and it's a complex beast.  Now copying this object may not be a good idea. Chances are that if you modify this object then you *want* the changes to propogate to every object that holds a reference. And even if you did copy it, do you need a shallow copy (a new instance but it's ivars references the same objects) or a deep copy (a new instance containing containing new copies of every ivar)? And the object in question may not even support `<NSCopying>`, meaning it can't technically be copied at all.

---

So to sum up:

- `copy`: Objects that are small, atomic bits of data without any internal references to other objects.
- `retain`: Nearly every other kind of object.

Comment: But what if you had a mutable string instead, and you modified it. Sorry but can we modify a mutable string?

Answer (score 7):

Client code can assign an NSMutableString object to an NSString property. If the property was defined as strong or some other non-copy attribute, then if the client later changes the mutable string, the property's value would now be different. By setting the property to be 'copy', a copy of the string value is made and this ensures the value can't change behind your back.

So basically you should use copy whenever the property is for a type that has a mutable counterpart and you want to ensure the value doesn't change on you.

Comment: This is doesn't really answer the question. OP is wondering what's special about strings? Why not copy any mutable object? @AlexWayne explains it pretty well.